# Cocoa: How to fit child to the parent?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, layout, interface-builder

How do you make a child view to fit the parent view and resize when parent resizes?

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use InterfaceBuilder and use constraints to set the inner view's edges to be equal to the super view's, unless I'm really missing something....